# Braking one-handed to signal down steep traffic-heavy slope

Tags: brakes, downhill, braking

I've just recently picked up biking and will be cycling to work when I start in a few weeks. One thing that's really bothering me on my route is a very steep hill that gets very busy during rush hour. At the bottom there's a traffic light where I have to turn right (I live in the UK, we drive on the left).

I've been doing the route off-peak to practice. Thus far it's been clear behind me each time, so I've just looked back and drifted right to position myself correctly before the right turn. However, if there's traffic behind me, I would not feel safe doing this manoeuvre without hand-signalling to the right.

Is it safe to just brake with my left hand on a steep hill? (I believe that's the rear brake on British bikes.) Can I initially brake with both hands then briefly take my right hand off to signal? I've literally never braked one-handed, so it kind of terrifies me. Sorry if these sound like dumb questions; I just don't want to get injured!

Thanks!

Comment: recommend a cycling proficiency course if you're genuinely having to ask this question. Drag braking the rear is perfectly normal and isn't going to unbalance the bike. Ideally, scrub off most of your speed, position your bike for the manoeuvre, then lower your arm and continue braking as normal

Comment: Well it has been literal years since I've been on a bike so cycling proficiency course wouldn't harm for sure. Thanks for the input:)

Comment: Feel free to join [chat] for a less structured discussion of alternatives.  An indication on google-maps of the specific intersection might help us suggest definite solutions.

Comment: Describe the intersection in detail, layout makes a big difference how to handle it.  Do the lights have pedestrian phases and is it a T or crossing? Bike control is much more important than indication to other drivers. Your though process has to be 'stay left, slow down, keep left, slow down, remain left, slow down....when safe come off brakes, indicate and move to right (UK opposite to US).  Better to come to a stop to the left (where its relatively safe) than blowing the intersection because you failed to brake.

Comment: Show us the intersection please - I started using Vale St in Bristol as an example but its probably less busy than yours.     A link like   https://goo.gl/maps/YedpadKq8pCVv4dv6   would be a great discussion starter.

Comment: Agrred with @Criggie It depends on the junction. Use an analogous one if you are concerned about privacy.

Comment: @hellzfc this has turned into a particularly popular question.  Lets keep the momentum ip - can you please show the intersection in question and there will be even more answers in the next couple days.

Answer (score 31):

As an confident road rider I'd do two major things.

1. I'd turn my head, look backward and make eye contact with the driver(s) just behind me to show intention, and maybe signal at this point.  Or I might not signal at all.  Then
2. take the lane.  You will be moving fast enough to slot-in with the cars because of the downhill.  I'd avoid being sidelined on the side of the road.  I'd also do this well-before the intersection; hard to say how far but even 50-100 metres out.

If I'm needing to brake hard, I'll use both hands, and leave signalling/indicating out of it completely.  You've already shown your intent by taking the lane and moving closer to the center-line.

---

Since your experience is lesser, feel free to not do any of that.  You have to be comfortable with your intent and actions.  So instead you could:

1. Get off and walk this bit.  Brake early, loose speed from the downhill, and simply walk across the roads before the intersection.
2. If permitted, you could ride on the footpath, though the UK doesn't allow this unless it's a specific shared path.
3. Find another route to work.  There's a fair assumption that the best route for a car is also the best route for a bike, when frequently there are alternatives only available to bikes.

Also, if other cyclists traverse this intersection then watch and observe their methods.  If it makes sense then emulate them, and if not, then don't.

Comment: +1, Especially looking for alternates - often the best cycle route, especially for inexperienced riders and roads without cycle lanes, is using quite side roads rather than busy main roads

Comment: There is I think also a general thing to take away here: Taking the lane is often a safe/safer thing to do.  I find that any time I am travelling at a large fraction of the speed limit I take the lane, even if I have no intention of turning.  Drivers are only minimally inconvenienced (I am travelling at a large fraction of the allowed speed after all) and if they do want to overtake, I would rather they not do so into oncoming traffic.  Taking the lane largely prevents that.

Comment: +1, I'd add that you may need to pull out earlier than expected even if you don't take the lane for a fair distance.  It's not always avoidable - my old commute had a fairly steep 50m to a stop just after leaving work, and the opposite direction was no better.  In that case taking the lane meant not tucking in after the row of parked cars.  Signalling was brief - very brief if a someone started to cross the road suddenly - but I often repeated it.  This was in the  UK too, on a bike with V-brakes + good pads

Comment: @maxf130 yes, but I find it a bit problematic to recommend this to a beginner. Whilst taking the whole lane is definitely warranted before a dangerous turn, and is generally fine if you really do travel at the speed limit anyway, it is obviously just rude if you really are blocking the traffic (to a beginner, 25 km/h might already feel _quite fast_).

Comment: @leftaroundabout quite true.  I mention this in the context of descending a steep hill were one has to brake to avoid breaking the speed limit in the first place. Probably the safest thing to do there, even for a beginner, is to descend at or near the speed limit while taking the lane.

Comment: That does require confidence to descend at such a speed of course, which is why the advice to walk that section is necessary is very good.

Comment: There may be traffic legislations that don't allow cyclists to move to the middle lane when turning left (right-hand side road-use) You may have to stop at the right side of the road, get off the bike and cross the junction on foot. Even if not required I'd do that until I'd gained more handling skills.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I find it much more rude if a motorist tries to overtake with less than 1.5m lateral distance. Because that endangers the life of the cyclist, apart from being forbidden (at least where I live). That's a very sane law. And the sooner we enact it on the roads, the better. It is the duty of any driver (motorized or not) to slow down and follow whenever overtaking is illegal. And overtaking bikes with oncoming traffic is illegal on the vast majority of 2-lane roads.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica as cyclists we don't have the power to “enact” that law, though. If an irresponsible motorist is forced to crawl behind a cyclist for two minutes or so because they take up the entire lane, the eventual overtaking is not going to be any safer (on the contrary, it'll likely be hasty, if not angry). — My personal opinion is that politics should ensure cyclists never need to drive on multi-lane roads in the first place. If you want to _change the world for the better_, that's the fight to take on, not some silly right-to-use-that-lane war against the cars.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Have you tried it? My experience is that, yes, many are angry. But on average there'll be a *lot* more space between you and the overtaking car. As long as we behave like we don't have any rights, we are going to be treated like we don't have any rights. The motorists won't change their behavior unless we signal back to them that their behavior is wrong.

Comment: @Carel I would love to know which country that is!

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Yep. Know someone killed that way, truck overtook at close range and sucked the cyclist behind him and under the next truck.

Comment: @Frank tragic, but honestly how is cmaster's suggestion helping with that? A truck generates significant suction even when it's on the other lane. When there's a truck behind me, I always get off the road entirely until it's gone. And don't blame “those reckless truck drivers” – we need trucks, they have no option but to use the roads, and for them it's _really_ difficult to perform safe overtaking maneuvers. Seriously, it only underlines my point that cyclists shouldn't need to put themselves anywhere near that kind of dangerous situation at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Germany, on main roads.

Comment: @Carel That's bizarre! Remind me to avoid cycling in Germany because I am perfectly happy to make a proper left turn in the turning lane.

Comment: @Carel Only when there's a mandatory bike path. In the absence of the blue sign, riding on the road is legal, in the absence of a dedicated bike path, it's mandated. And whenever you are riding on the road, the center of the lane is the place for you to be. Like any odd motorcycle does as well. Motorcycles are not wider than bikes, and you generally don't see them trying to behave as if they were not there. The legal situation of safety distances is identical for motorcycles and bikes, the condition being simply to be a one-tracked vehicle.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Carel's view is a bit off. See my last comment for the details.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree with all that too. Near where I live there's a main road to the nearest town and one or two cyclists use their road bikes to commute from outlying villages on that road. Every time I see them I think, "why??". That road has huge trucks absolutely caning it almost back to back. And it's twisty with miles of no-overtaking lines. There are alternative routes but a bit less comfortable for road bikes. Most everyone has a mountain bike and commutes by trail here though.

Comment: People - remember comments are for improving the Q or A, and the chat (while interesting) should be over in [chat]

Answer (score 17):

Firstly, congrats on both posting for the first time and for deciding to commute on a bike! Many of us commute on bikes in the UK and everyone started somewhere!

If you're not 100% confident with ANY part of your journey, you should just stop, walk the challenging bit, and then get on your bike again to continue. There is absolutely no shame in doing that, and you don't want to mess around with heavy traffic unless you're both confident (in your abilities as a cyclist) and experienced. As already mentioned, you might want to consider some sort of cycling course, there are plenty available, a lot for free, all over the UK. Maybe you have some friends who are more experienced riders to go out with and practise / enjoy your ride as well.

Realistically, when you turn, you should take up the whole lane that you're on and then manoeuvre safely using both hands. So you should signal, as early as you want, in an obvious way to indicate your intention, once you KNOW that the car behind you KNOWS what you are doing that's when then you manoeuvre.

In the same way that you should not be signalling whilst turning, you should signal before a turn, take your space and then turn. Cornering/braking one handed in 100% not recommended for inexperienced riders. It will only cause more damage than good, usually to the rider.

Comment: Thanks for your response! A cycling proficiency course probably wouldn't go amiss for me :-) I have been getting off and pushing several times, particularly at roundabouts. I think as people start going back to work and there's more bikers on the road during commuting hours I'll be able to watch what others do and hopefully pick up some good practise!

Comment: That's a good idea actually, see if you can get to some awkward junctions early and just relax there and wait for other cyclists to see how they do it. Mind you, won't stop you from being intimidated when you try yourself. Maybe start a petition for better cycle paths???? haha

Answer (score 10):

> I've literally never braked one handed so it kind of terrifies me.

It is terrific for a reason and you have to practice somewhere safe.

If you hold the front set with only one hand and do brake, your body momentum will try to turn the front wheel. If you don't counter this movement, you'll fall or get where you don't intend to.

Comment: Good that you spell this out explicitly – though it's probably clear to most here, including the OP. I personally find single-handed braking _pretty_ difficult. (Despite being comfortable with technical MTB riding that most cyclists would probably never attempt; but I really need both hands on the bars for steep descends.)

Comment: It depends. If you have brake handles (or additional brake handles) near the center, it is easier and requires much less back muscles.

Comment: One handed riding and braking with the rear brake only is relatively safe and easy since you can’t produce a lot of stopping power. One handed front braking to the point where the rear wheel leaves the ground takes serious core strength and practice.

Comment: To state the obvious: ^^ this is what can happen. A steep downhill will make it even worse, and heavy traffic will make it much, MUCH worse. If you're not comfortable, listen to your instincts and walk the bike.

Answer (score 8):

As a cyclist in the UK your use of the bicycle on the road is governed by the Highway Code. You are [not required to use hand signals](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/53789/is-using-hand-signals-a-legal-requirement-in-the-uk), because it is acknowledged both hands are required for operating the bike safely.

In the event you cannot use hand signals, make other road users aware of your intention through eye contact, body position on the bike, road positioning and so on.

As other answers have said, if the better option is to dismount then do that.

Answer (score 8):

Do a 2 stage  turn manoeuvre.

or

I do this often when traffic is too important.

Comment: Good video links - these are also termed "hook turns", which is nothing to do with "being  left/right hooked"

Comment: I was about to make a sketch and write a lengthy explanation. This is the best solution and should be upvoted more. It elegantly solves the "need to brake with one hand" problem on the side.

Comment: Every urban cyclist needs to know how to do this anywhere they feel uneasy about turning from the inside (even if that is allowed). @Criggie thanks for sharing that name, now I don't have to describe this move using hand waving and yelling.

Comment: It is a safe alternative for the situation. But when I look at those videos I feel that 10 seconds more advance green for cyclists would allow them to cross the street in one go, much better for all. So street designers, safe money on tarmac paint, use the green for cyclists only and have them cross the road safely in one go.

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no shame to stop and walk the difficult/dangerous bit. Actually, it is stupid not doing so and risking too much when one is not confident.
2. With expirience goes confidence. Now you need to stop and walk the crossection everytime. In a month you will stop only because really heavy trafic, then because of slippery road, later you will do the turn without any struggle...
3. Visibility is cyclist's first safeguard. Use headlights and taillights. You can get yourself [lights with turn signals](https://hybridbikereviewed.com/bicycle-turn-signals-review/) which works like on a motorbike. You can have them mounted on the frame, seatpost, backpack, helmet...

Comment: 1 and 2 are good points, but putting turn signals on the bike is not going to help OP's confidence.  Drivers may or may not act as you expect when the indicator is activated.

Answer (score 3):

Might I also add that for me (15 years plus commuting), I find that travelling on a bicycle in traffic at rush hour is very different to travelling on an empty road, largely because very often the traffic (cars) are not moving.

If this is a busy route, you may well find that you are going to be negotiating your way through a queue of stationary traffic as opposed to flowing cars, and this is a slightly different thing to deal with.  Finding your way through traffic is also a learning curve, but it may be that you will be going a lot slower than on an empty road.

---

As an addendum, braking with one hand on the bars will never be fully safe - you just need to be careful with what is around you.

I have been cycling a similar route for approx. 8 years, without major incident (thankfully).  However, the closest I have come to serious injury in this time was when indicating into the outer lane on a flat road with minimal traffic.  The car in front of me in the outer lane, with no traffic for a couple of hundred metres decided to brake suddenly to avoid a plastic bag, just as I had put my hand out to signal.  It was only luck that stopped me from going straight into their rear windscreen.

My takeaway from this was that I was too close to that car when trying to manoeuvre.  I think we're all still learning at some level!

Comment: Excellent point there - slow-moving cars rarely if ever anticipate or check for a cyclist passing them on the inside (ie up the left in the UK)

Comment: Very good point there, yes. Actually come to think of it, I don't know what the regulations are like in the UK about this kind of thing but maybe a good idea would be a damn bright, blinking LED.

Answer (score 3):

Never ever risk your stability and complete control of your bike in going downhill, much less take one hand off the handlebar even for a second when you may need to brake strongly on a steep slope. It's a recipe for disaster even for highly experienced bikers. You can't beat physics, this is all about vehicle dynamics and you want to stay safe.

If you lose stability and drop to the ground or even just go swerving uncontrolledly downhill with heavy traffic behind you, that's the closest you can avoidably get to "this is it" in an up-to-there normal everyday traffic situation. Cars and heavy vehicles can't beat physics either - braking is much less effective downhill. Better not count on a vehicle behind you being able to conduct serious braking at all.

So your first priority is to keep your ability to go straight and follow the road (or to get off the road in a controlled and timely way if that's preferable), along with your ability to completely control your speed and not find yourself off the exact place and trajectory on the road where you wanted to go in the first place.

If that means you can't signal at any given moment, because that means taking one hand off your bike, then you can't signal at that moment. When that's not an option, so is getting into that situation where you have to fill too many requirements simultaneously.

Fully taking the lane is a good idea where it helps, in a way where cars behind you can easily control their own driving (no imposing surprises on anyone), if it makes truly impossible for cars behind you to do things that can turn out risky for yourself, such as overtaking narrowly.

That's not being rude when it's what it takes to stay safe for all parties involved. And you have the same right to be there as every other road user (provided you are keeping to the regulations). If it *is* rude in a given situation, then there's something different wrong already. By doing it properly, you are not just protecting yourself, you are also protecting the respective driver from prosecution in an accident that could arise.

If a particular place or situation is such that you're out of these options when you go there, you probably don't want to be riding in that place or situation. Protect yourself and use whatever other option is available. You want to feel fully confident with what you're doing *and* with all involved persons' complete control of the situation.

Comment: Concur - I'd be taking the lane the whole way down the hill, and only moving out of the way if it were safe, for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your main question is this:

> Is it safe to just brake with my left hand on a steep hill?

It depends on the conditions. If you have an icy, or slushy, downhill, then you should probably avoid using the front brake at all and make sure you have a long deceleration using back brake primarily.

If it's normal conditions and you need to brake, your front brake does most of the work. Use the front brake to decelerate well in advance, and then if you need to resist acceleration just use the back brake.

Your peripheral context though is how to manage that particular junction. My advice is to be in the middle of the lane well in advance with traffic behind you, knowing that they can't assume you want to turn left. Be a bit assertive and because it's a commute, the majority of drivers will get to know you over time.

Main thing, though, just don't worry too much and go for it. Keep reading, asking other bikers, etc. Pretty quick you'll be dancing through things like you've been doing it all your life. There's first times for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing is that you don’t do anything unexpected. Suddenly cutting across a lane because you are too scared to look behind and indicate is unexpected and you are rightfully concerned about doing that.

If you have to slow down before you feel confident to look behind you and signal with your hand, do so very gradually. No sudden, unexpected braking maneuvers. This is also true if you want to stop at the side of the road in order to walk across the intersection.

Once you’ve slowed down enough it shouldn’t be too hard to stay at that speed (or further decelerate) with your rear brake only. It should then be possible to look behind you and indicate.

Practice one handed braking maneuvers with each hand. There are lots of situations where you suddenly have to brake one handed for example while indicating or while drinking from your bottle. Be aware that braking with the rear brake only produces less stopping power than both brakes together or the front brake only, especially if the road is wet or surface is bad (manhole covers, painted lines, zebra crossings, pebbles etc.). But you can try that on a quiet road or grass. Braking to the point where the rear wheel locks up is quite controllable and safe, unless you do it in a turn.

If you find it very hard to ride straight with one hand only it could be that your handle bars are too low down or too far forward (or counter intuitively your seat could be too far forward which makes it harder to let go of the bar).

Answer (score 1):

As Philip says, there are indicators available for bikes; a rear-view mirror wouldn't go amiss either. However, I don't have either on my race bike.

In the situation you describe I would indicate really early, then put the hand back on (depending on how steep/fast), while setting up for the corner, scrubbing my speed nice and early, then another quick solid signal and turn.
The earlier you set up the easier it is to time your turn with any potential gap in oncoming traffic; you may even need to speed up again. 
Once you've slowed down, the force in you're arms will drop enough to safely take a hand off. It is sketchy, signalling while braking and looking out for traffic. Doesn't leave much room for looking out for potholes etc. If you're using just the front brake you risk the front wheel washing out, or going OTB from a pothole, or if you're just on the rear brake, you lack stopping power and could slide out (esp if wet!). Hence, brake early as poss, open up a gap between you and the car in front so you've got room to manoeuvre. If you're having to stay on the brakes because there's a car in front, you should have slowed enough to brake one-handed. Keep the hand signal clear and quick, it should obvious to any driver behind what you're about to do anyway.

What this issue emphasises is that cyclists can't always signal what they're doing safely, so give them space.

Practise braking while standing up out of the saddle, alternating between front and rear brake, shifting weight back and forth. Get familiar with the sensation of the forces and how they affect the traction of the bike.

Answer (score 1):

I ride a route that is very similar to yours in the US just lanes are reversed.

My thoughts are this:

- Get a rearview mirror. This lets you more easily see what is behind you while still focusing in front of you. A bar mount mirror or one on the drops is what I use. Rearview radar is pretty cool and nice to augment a mirror, but even with rear radar, I still make final lane change decisions after verifying with a mirror or head turn if on my right side (i.e. non mirror side).
- I would also get a rear safety light to improve visibility of you to cars behind you.
- I think the first priority for you is to maintain control of your bike. This usually means on steep hills brake with both front and rear brakes (i.e. using both hands).
- The other good part in the UK is bikes can "take a lane" as in take a full lane like a car or motorcycle and the cars behind them have to respect the bike's right of way.
- With all of that said, I would take the lane somewhere when there is no traffic, signal or change lanes when you know no cars are behind you into the turning lane, and be on your way. In the clip below, you see I change into the turning lane as early as possible so if there was a car behind me they would have to effectively be in an illegal position. Obviously be pragmatic to double check for cars behind you because it is one thing to be right in the eyes of the law vs.  who wins when it comes to the laws of physics if a 2500 lbs car fails to yield to your right of way on a bike.
- This is what it looks like in the US for me when I have to take a left hand turn at the bottom of a hill. Note I brake with both front and rear brakes to slow from those speeds.

Comment: What (if anything) would you do differently if it were **steep** like OP's situation, say a 10% or 20% grade ?  That's a ~5 degree or 10 degree angle to the horizontal, where the overlay suggests this peaks at 2%

Comment: @Criggie I would probably try to hit 45 mph on the bike just to cross that off the bucket list ; ). I don’t have much desire to go any faster than that. I would definitely brake earlier too. However, I still say the first priority is staying in control and then lane control/signaling.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming across previous answers, I don't see any reference to how your brake cables are orientated. i.e. does your left hand activate the rear brake and your right hand active the front or vice versa?

As an Aussie and sympathetic 'keeping on the left' cycle user I'm cognisant of your problem as described.

Just like *driving on the left* or *driving on the right* is another old convention issue; you may not be aware that bicycles brakes can be set up  either **left-rear/right-front** vs. **left-front/right-rear**.  It can honestly boil downto what you've grown up with or adjusted to personally; but depending on your dominant hand; most braking modulation and precision is performed by actuating the front brake.

It's a little longer in its wording but I can recommend an article by the original great internet bicycle sage Sheldon Brown here: [Braking and Turning Your Bicycle](https://sheldonbrown.com/brakturn.html), which better fleshes the issues with understanding braking; and how you may better improve your technique.

best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get an electronic turning signal indicator and use that to signal.
2. Claim the center of the auto lane so that even inattentive drivers should be aware of your presence.
3. Eye contact with the driver behind you, in your mirror perhaps, sounds like a good idea if possible; in any case have an escape plan in mind if the following vehicle fails to keep distance when you slow to turn.
4. Braking and/or turning one-handed, at speed, coming off the bottom of a hill, in traffic, sounds very dangerous.
5. If you are not confident about doing this safely, choose another route, maybe three left turns to make one right turn. (You said you drive on the left in your country.)

Please be careful:

Seth Vidal, a well-known member of Durham's (North Carolina US) cycling community, and the creator of the yum software update tool for RedHat/Fedora linux systems, was, I believe, biking home from work when a hit-and-run driver killed him at age 37.

http://ghostbikes.org/durham/seth-vidal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)

Comment: Electronic indicators are vanishingly rare on a bike and most drivers will have never seen one.  They may not even be legal depending on location.  Who knows what a driver's reaction might be if only given a few seconds.  The rest of your points are excellent.

Comment: @Criggie: 1. Turn indicators are never a guarantee that drivers will respond appropriately. They are a way to indicate your intention without taking your hards off the steering control.

Comment: @Criggie: 2.  Are you saying that drivers understand a blinking light on one side of a vehicle is a turn signal, only if they have seen them on that exact kind of vehicle before?

Comment: Drivers may not comprehend in the short time available, what the intent is.  Also there's no legal requirement for vehicles to give way to other vehicles coming in from the kerb.  Its too chancy to assume every driver will know what you want with the blinker, and react in the expected way.  I personally remember the first time I saw one of those super-fancy animated indicators, and it was sufficient distraction to almost cause an accident.  So in that respect, different can be a bad thing with unexpected reactions.  I'd take the lane relatively early, or there's no shame in walking it.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that a lot of people will disagree with this answer, but what I do when unable to free a hand to signal is to stick out the corresponding leg in in a very obvious and visible way.

Comment: So, compromising your balance and bike control instead of taking a hand off the bars?  This doesn't sound very safe, and there's no guarantee anyone behind you will understand what you're doing.  (I certainly wouldn't expect that to be a signal, unless it's "help, I'm falling off my bike!")